# Switching languages in bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I would like to have a bibliography with both Cyrillic and Latin and the main document language being English. How can I make biblatex to automatically switch between languages? (without using XeTeX as suggested by some) The minimal example returns an error if the main language is English. However, with the main language being Russian the document works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend = biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
%\selectlanguage{russian} %if the main document language is Russian the bibliography is compiled without any problem.
This is a test. \parencite{Bara2006,Baranov2001}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The .bib entries are

```
@book{Bara2006,
address = {New York},
author = {Bara, Judith},
publisher = {Routledge},
title = {{English Citation entry}},
year = {2006}
}

@book{Baranov2001,
address = {Санкт-Петербугр},
author = {Баранов, Николай А},
title = {{Эволюция взглядов}},
year = {2001}
}
```

Comment: You could add a `language` key in each of your bibentries (ex: `language=russian` or `language=english`).

Comment: I was thinking about that but unfortunately results in the same error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must add `hyphenation` and `language` keys to each of your bibentries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{filecontents*}{library.bib}
@book{Bara2006,
  address = {New York},
  author = {Bara, Judith},
  publisher = {Routledge},
  title = {{English Citation entry}},
  year = {2006},
  language={english},
  hyphenation={english}
}
@book{Baranov2001,
  address = {Санкт-Петербугр},
  author = {Баранов, Николай А},
  title = {{Эволюция взглядов}},
  year = {2001},
  language={russian},
  hyphenation={russian}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{library.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test. \parencite{Bara2006,Baranov2001}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is already great and works on my other file. However, the problem is that I am using a reference manager (Mendeley) that doesn't provide for a `hypenation` field for .bib-export. I would need to add it manually to all my entries and would loose all the changes when I build a new .bib file.

Comment: @shkelda Biber can copy the contents of `language` to `hyphenation` for you. Just add `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource=language]\step[fieldset=hyphenation,origfieldval]}}}` to your preamble.

Comment: @shkelda BTW: It is actually just the `hyphenation` field you need to get localized bibliography entries. This field only accepts babel language identifiers. The `language` field specifies the language of the work for printing. It can be a literal string or a babel identifier.

Comment: Question remaining: Why is there no issue when the main document language is set to Russian, as opposed to the problems coming with setting it to English as the first language?

Comment: @shkelda Because with Russian as the main language babel loads the proper font encodings for you. With English, you need to load them yourself with, say, `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}`. Either way `babel=other` requires `hyphenation` to work properly.

Comment: Hah, that's the trick I was looking for. In fact I don't get an error now when compiling a mixed bibliography with the main language being English and that even without the hyphenation field declared.

Comment: `hyphenation` is aliased to `langid` for backward compatibilty. However, neither did the job for me. My `.bbl` file indeed contained a `\field{langid}{<language>}` but the correct hyphenation did not occur... Should the key be placed _first_ in entry?

Comment: @hdl The order of keys in the `.bbl` file is irrelevant. Did you choose the correct language id (in `.bib` and with `babel`)?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the information. I just narrowed down my issue to a French expression containing an apostrophe (e.g. « l'élargissement ») that is not hyphenated at all unless I issue `\selectlanguage{french}` before `\printbibliography`.