# Typeset a bibliography with entries in several different languages

Tags: biblatex, languages, biber

What is the best way to typeset a bibliography that contains several entries in a number of different language scripts like Latin, Cyrillic, Chinese, Japanese and Vietnamese.

The question centers around the issue if there is (or not) a solution withing pdflatex, for example biber+babel+biblatex or if one HAS o move to XeLaTeX and to Polyglossia.

I currently have a file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[OT2,T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english,french,german,polish,portuguese,romanian,spanish,russian,vietnam]{babel}

\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{book-lib.bib}

\addbibresource{russian.bib}

\addbibresource{vietnamese.bib}

%\addbibresource{chinese.bib}

%\addbibresource{japanese.bib}


\begin{document}

This is a test.

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
```

that stops working as soon as one adds the russian/vietnames biblio enties, with complaints like:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \cyrs unavailable in encoding T1.
```

when the Russian entries are added and and more as the other are added.

Comment: Using `biber` (and, perforce, `biblatex`): it is designed for unicode input.

Comment: What do you mean?  How to do it technical with bibtex or biblatex/biber or logical, like should the bibliography be sorted for languages, first Latin books, then Cyrillic books etc.?

Comment: adding to jon's suggestion: with the `hyphenation` field and the `babel=hyphen` option, [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/biblatex) also makes easy language-sensitive hyphenation. See [Switching languages in bibliography with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96469/5872)

Comment: To address the error you mentioned: have you tried loading `T2A` font encoding for cyrillic (as suggested in a comment to the answer I linked before)?