# Switching languages in bibliography with biblatex (completely!)

Tags: biblatex, babel-french

This is a take on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96469/switching-languages-in-bibliography-with-biblatex#96474). In the print,

> In : LE JOUR (AAAA)

should be

> Dans : LE JOUR (AAAA).

Is it feasible, how?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto,backend=biber,babel=other]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

%\addbibresource{foo.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib}
@article{bar
  ,author =       "AUTHOR"
  ,title =        "TITLE"
  ,journal =      "JOUR"
  ,year =         "YYYY"
}

@article{lebar
  ,author =       "AUTEUR"
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}

A bare citation command: \autocite{bar}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \textcite{bar} said \dots

Une citation: \autocite{lebar}.

Une citation au milieu du texte: Comme \textcite{lebar} a dit \dots


\printbibliography
```

\end{document}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both entries are actually completely in French - at least to the extent controlled by `biblatex`.

A short look at [`french.lbx` (l. 413, in `biblatex` 3.13a)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/bcc7970e4020533cf9cf430b222b5699c1bd92f1/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/french.lbx#L413) shows that `biblatex` translates "in" into French as "in". If you want "dans" instead, you just need to tell `biblatex` about that.

Note that at least in the specific constellation of your MWE the `autolang` option and the `langid` (formerly `hyphenation`) field have no influence on the output. `biblatex` already prints the entries in French since it adapts to the main language of the document, which is French.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,autolang=other]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  in = {dans},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{bar
  ,author =       "AUTHOR"
  ,title =        "TITLE"
  ,journal =      "JOUR"
  ,year =         "YYYY"
}
@article{lebar
  ,author =       "AUTEUR"
  ,title =        "TITRE"
  ,journal =      "LE JOUR"
  ,year =         "AAAA"
  ,language={french}
  ,hyphenation={french}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
A bare citation command: \autocite{bar}.

A citation command for use in the flow of text: As \textcite{bar} said \dots

Une citation: \autocite{lebar}.

Une citation au milieu du texte: Comme \textcite{lebar} a dit \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: AUTEUR. << TITRE >> . Dans : LE JOUR (AAAA).//AUTHOR. << TITLE >> . Dans : JOUR (YYYY).]